How to open modal sheet only once using Bloc
Scenario is I want to open modal sheet when state is GetExperienceLoadedState and AppStrings.isFeedbackForFinancing == true and I am calling an API on initState method.
Modal sheet is appearing but the issue is it is appearing multiple times. and this number of times changes when i come back to the screen. like initially it is 2, then 4, then 6 or sometimes 8 and so on.
here is my code of bloc
Future _getExperience(GetExperienceEvent event, emit) async {
    try {
      emit(GetExperienceLoadingState());
      final allExperience = await getExperienceUsecase.getExperience(
          languageKey: event.languageKey);
      _getExperienceList = allExperience;

      emit(GetExperienceLoadedState());
     
    } on InvalidInputException catch (e) {
      emit(GetExperienceErrorState(
        errorMessage: e.message ?? '',
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(GetExperienceErrorState(errorMessage: e.toString()));
    }
  }

here is my ** screen code**
bool _isBottomSheetShown = false;

@override
  void initState() {
    _feedbackBloc = BlocProvider.of<FeedbackBloc>(context);

    // Conditional feedback calls
    if (AppStrings.isFeedbackForFinancing == true) {
      _callFeedbackExperienceEvent();
    }
    super.initState();
  }

 Future<void> _callFeedbackExperienceEvent() async {
    _feedbackBloc = BlocProvider.of<FeedbackBloc>(context);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _feedbackBloc.add(GetExperienceEvent(languageKey: '${context.locale}'));
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final height = context.screenHeight;
    final width = context.screenWidth;
    final readBlocContext = context.read<DashboardBloc>();
    final readRewardBlocContext = context.read<RewardsBloc>();
    final _feedbackBloc = context.read<FeedbackBloc>();
    log('isFeedbackForFinancing:::  ${AppStrings.isFeedbackForFinancing} ${widget.isFromFianancing}');

    return Padding(
        padding: AppSpacing.leftRightPadding,
        child: BlocConsumer<DashboardBloc, DasbhboardState>(
            bloc: _dasboardBloc,
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is AccountIncomeErrorState ||
                  state is AccountBalanceErrorState ||
                  state is RecommendedOfferErrorState ||
                  state is PointsCatActionLoadingState) {
                HelperFunctions.showToast(context.text.genericError);
              }
            },
            builder: (context, dashboardState) {
              return BlocConsumer<RewardsBloc, RewardState>(
                  bloc: _rewardsBloc,
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    if (state is RewardErrorState) {
                      HelperFunctions.showToast(context.text.genericError);
                    }
                  },
                  builder: (context, rewardsState) {
                    bool isLoading =
                        dashboardState is AccountIncomeLoadingState ||
                            rewardsState is RewardLoadingState ||
                            _rewardsBloc is PointsCatActionLoadingState ||
                            _feedbackBloc is GetFeedbacksLoadingState ||
                            dashboardState is RecommendedOfferLoadingState;

                    if (isLoading) {
                      return _customDashboardShimmerListView();
                    } else {
                      // log('_feedbackBloc.customerFeedbackStatus ${_feedbackBloc.customerFeedbackStatus}');
                      return CustomRefreshIndicatorWidget(
                        onRefresh: _refreshData,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                //some widget

                                 BlocConsumer<FeedbackBloc, FeedbackState>(
                                  bloc: _feedbackBloc,
                                  
                                  listener: (context, feedbackState) {
                                   
                                    
                                    if (feedbackState is GetExperienceErrorState) {
                                      HelperFunctions.showToast(context.text.genericError);
                                    }

                                    if (feedbackState is GetExperienceLoadedState ) {
                                      if (AppStrings.isFeedbackForFinancing == true &&      _isBottomSheetShown==false) {

                                        _isBottomSheetShown = true; 
                                        _showBottomSheetWidget();
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  
                                

                                  builder: (BuildContext context, FeedbackState feedbackState) {
                                    return SizedBox();
                                  },
                                ),
//some widget


 Future _showBottomSheetWidget() {
    final readFeedbackBlocContext = context.read<FeedbackBloc>();

    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: AppColors.kWhiteColor,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (context) => FeedbackModalSheetWidget(
          featureIds: readFeedbackBlocContext.financingTypeFeatureIds,
          feedbackOptionList: readFeedbackBlocContext.getExperienceList),
    ).then((result) {
      setState(() {
        AppStrings.isFeedbackForFinancing = false;
        _isBottomSheetShown = false; // Allow modal to be shown again later
      });
    });
  }

i also added this condition _isBottomSheetShown==false if modal appears once, then it shouldn't appear again, but it is not working, i guess the problem is on listener but i couldn't identify it. please help me to fix this issue.

this screen is likely to be recreated. check if initState() is called once, then check if _getExperience(..) in bloc is called once.
